# Couple of questions about the Oracle forms builder

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I find the net to be depleted of info about the Oracle Forms Builder so I will ask here.

1. I created a menu form where I have 6 buttons. All of them have to open another form. What's the syntax of open_form(???) on the button?
2. I created a form where i add records to a child table. However I don't want people to be able to edit the secondary key, only select it from the list of primary keys of the parent. How could i do that?
3. This one is the long one. I will need a lot of help with the last form - searching in the parent table. Where could I find any info on that.

   a)I'll need to select which column is being searched

   b)Select what data will be displayed with check boxes

   c)If the selected column is the primary key column, also display the child table check boxes which, if checked, will display the columns.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can open the Form builder and hit F1 or Help. Then type Open_Form in index/search and copy/paste the code. I'd suggest reading about difference between Open_Form and Call_Form. Most of the times Call_Form is used.
2. The secondary key will be the display item, which will not let any user to navigate to that item. Or you can set properties of text_item - insert/update allowed to false.
3. Probably you will need to create view(s) or populate your block(s) on the fly with select statements. The views probably are the easier and best way. You can build your form-blocks based on those views and manipulate with data, check boxes etc...

Answer (score 0):

1. for calling other forms from a main form on which you have placed buttons to call other forms.....
   write this in WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED Trigger  call_form('C:\Users\Messi\Desktop\school\CITIES.fmx');
   it is the adress of the compiled file of the that oracle form.....NOTE that it is not the .fmb file adress.